Analysis for Parallel Mediation Model with Categorical DV
Does anyone have recommendations for running a parallel mediation model, with a multi-categorical outcome variable (3 levels)?? Here is a breakdown of all the variables that I need to input into the model...
Independent Variable (X) = Condition Assignment (3 levels; categorical)
Mediator #1 (M1) = Blameworthiness (continuous)
Mediator #2 (M2) = Dangerousness (continuous)
Dependent Variable (Y) = Verdict (3 levels; categorical)
I have tried Hayes Process in SPSS (model 4) and although it will accept a categorical outcome variable, the limitations of interpreting such a model based on OLS are pretty significant. Therefore, I am trying to find a better alternative. Prefer any solutions that are suitable for SPSS or R.
THANK YOU!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is Y ordered or multinomial? R lavaan can handle ordinal outcomes, PROCESS cannot.

@Sointu Y is multinomial... and lavaan work with multinomial outcome variables?

No, just ordinal. I don't know any software that would manage a mediation model with a multinomial outcome. MPlus might, but I'm not sure.
